# ES6/JavaScript - declaring variables without let/const

Tags: javascript

In JavaScript / ES6.

What happens when you have something like:

```js
x = 5;

console.log(x);  // 5
```

Is the interpreter automatically adding `let` at runtime? Why is this working without errors?

Comment: You've created an implicit global variable in a non-strict context.

Comment: If you are in strict mode (which i would argue you always should be) that would throw an exception and not create an implicit global. Also that isn't ES6 related, that behavior was present before ES6.

Comment: Because you didn't use "use strict"

Comment: Where is your `use strict;` string?

Comment: Seems some minifers benefit from dropping those characters but otherwise use the designated keyword

Comment: See [also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript?rq=1).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

By omitting `let`, `const`, or `var` in non-strict mode, you create a property on the global object.

By the way, `babel` will add `"use strict";` by default. So you will get a error with `babel`.

You can try it here: https://babeljs.io/repl/

Answer (score 2):

In this case, x becomes a global variable. Try to avoid this as global variables can be hard on the browser.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the previous two answers:

Assignment without the keyword returns the value:

```js
> const x = 4
undefined
> let y = 4
undefined
> var z = 4
undefined
> a = 4
4
```

And dropping the keyword is used in some minifiers to cutdown on payload

Answer (score 1):

then you're not declaring/defining a variable; instead you're creating/defining (or overwriting) some global/window obj property

```
x = 5;
```

is the same as

```
window.x = 5;
```

You can check it with `window`, or with the `this` keyword in your browser console; look at the global/window obj properties, you'll see the `x` property there.